# QuantConv2D relation to GEMMlowp

Tags: tensorflow

I've followed the documentation and TF Github code and couldn't find the relation between `QuantizedConv2D` to `GEMMlowp`.

Does `QuantizedConv2D` use, implicitly, in a way the `QuantizedMatMul(quantized_matmul_op.cc)`, under the hood, where the latter calls `GemmlowpMultiply` explicitly? Otherwise how the `QuantizedConv2D` using the great benefit of Google `GEMM HW` platform specific implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You can process your input matrices in a convolution layer in order to perform a matrix multiplication with them. Read this great article, especially the chapter "How GEMM works for Convolutions". https://petewarden.com/2015/04/20/why-gemm-is-at-the-heart-of-deep-learning/